# Are Google and Yandex maps similar?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, yandex-maps

I heard that Google Maps coordinates are not compatible with Yandex map coordinates. Is it true? Can I use same coords for both map apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both use ordinary latitude and longitude coordinates, just like everyone else, so i see no reason why they should not correspond.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm it. If you happen to code ruby and/or Javascript/Coffescript, you may be interested in this code: I [added basic support for Yandex.Maps APIv2 support to gmaps4rails gem](https://github.com/velhas-net/Google-Maps-for-Rails/tree/Yandex.Maps) some month ago. Now this gem supports both via one interface from application perspective. Switching from Google Maps to Yandex requires a change in a single parameter named `provider`. API support is extensible, and suggestions or pull requests are very welcome.

Example:

Google map with markers:

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json},
 "map_options" =>  { "provider" => "openlayers"}) %>
```

Yandex map with markers:

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json},
 "map_options" =>  { "provider" => "yandex"}) %>
```

Hope this helps.